# Подскажите плагин wordpress для редактирования профиля пользователя

Tags: php, html, wordpress, плагин, админка

Приветствую. Подскажите плагин wordpress для создания отдельной страницы редактирования профиля пользователя похожего как в админке wordpress, только более упрощенную с возможностью изменения полей и загрузки аватарки

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вот то что сможет вам помочь http://wp-skins.info/2008/12/31/kak-sdelat-profil-polzovatelya-v-wordpress.html